# blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload with Laravel How to integrate?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, image-uploading

Trying to build my upload images part of my site and wanted to use blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload instead of hardcoding everything from scratch. However I am new too all that, could you tell me **HOW to integrate that plugin with my Laravel structure** ?

Where do I put all the files ? In vendors folder ? Or should I split all the folders and put their js folder in mine etc???

If you know a tutorial it is even better...
Couldn't find anything good with google.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too broad, try specifying your problems.

Comment: Ok reformulated the end to try to make is clearer :)

Comment: You can put the js and css files into public/ folder or use a manager like Bower to do that for you.

Comment: @delmadord what about the dependencies ? `  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": ">=1.6",
    "blueimp-tmpl": ">=2.5.3",
    "blueimp-load-image": ">=1.11.0",
    "blueimp-canvas-to-blob": ">=2.1.0"`

Comment: My bad they are "included" .... damn this is not intuitive!!! :p

Answer (score 7):

You can try this code I'm posting to help others.

The first step is to define the upload page and upload handling `Route`s, like this:

```
Route::get('image_', function() {
    return View::make('image.upload-form');
});

Route::post('image_updade', 'ImageController@postUpload');
```

Make your `image.upload-form` view something like this (I'm using simple HTML, not a `Blade` template):

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('url' => 'image_updade', 'files' => true, 'id' => 'myForm')) ?> 
    Name: <input type='file' name='image' id='myFile'/>
    <br/>
    Comment: <textarea name='comment'></textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type='submit' value='Submit Comment' /> 
<?php echo Form::close() ?>
```

Now you need to add the JavaScript files in that view page's `<HEAD>` tag:

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js'></script> 
<script src='http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js'></script> 

<script> 
    // Wait for the DOM to be loaded 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        // Bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function() {
            alert('Thank you for your comment!');
        });

        $('#myFile').change(function() {
            $('#myForm').submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Finally, here's a simple example of code for the `ImageController@postUpload` controller to get the uploaded file, and move it to a destination folder:

```
<?php

    class ImageController extends BaseController {

        public function getUploadForm() {
            return View::make('image/upload-form');
        }

        public function postUpload() {

            $file = Input::file('image');
            $input = array('image' => $file);
            $rules = array( 'image' => 'image');
            $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

            if ( $validator->fails() ){
                return Response::json(['success' => false, 'errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()]);
            }
            else {
                $destinationPath = 'files/';
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                Input::file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                return Response::json(['success' => true, 'file' => asset($destinationPath.$filename)]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is csrf_token in your form?